# why is $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+k}{k^k}=0?$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

My question is, why is $$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+k}{k^k}=0?$$ I tried to prove it with L'Hospital's rule: 
$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+k}{k^k}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{kk^{k-1}}$ but I don't get 0..
Maybe I have to use $k^k=e^{kln(k)}$. How to calculate the limit?

Comment: $\lim_{k\to+\infty}k^k=+\infty$, and $\left(k\mapsto k^k\right)'\neq kk^{k-1}$.

Comment: The derivative of $ \ k^k \ $ is not $ \ k \ \cdot \ k^{k-1} \ $ because both base and exponent are the same _variable_.  You need to treat that using logarithmic differentiation, since it is the function $ \ x^x  \ $ .

Comment: You don't even need l'Hopital in any event because the term can be written as $ \ k^{-k} \ + \ k^{-k+1} \ $ which certainly has a limit at infinity of zero.

Answer (score 4):

$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1+k}{k^k}=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k^{k}} + \lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{1}{k^{k-1}} = 0 + 0 = 0$$

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you don't really *need* L'Hospital here, as $$\frac{1+k}{k^k}=\frac{1}{k^k} + \frac{1}{k^{k-1}} < \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{k}$$ if $k>2$, and the limit becomes obvious.

---

However, if you insist on L'Hospital, you did not use L'Hospital correctly.

You need to calculate the derivatives of $1+k$ (which, correct, is $1$), and of $k^k$. The derivative of $k^k$ is tricky to calculate, but it is **not** equal to $k\cdot k^{k-1}$ (as that would simply be equal to $k^k$). The rule

$$(x^n)' = n\cdot x^{n-1}$$
is true **only if $n$ is a constant**!!!

To calculate the derivative of $k^k$, write it as $$k^k=e^{\ln k^k} = e^{k\cdot \ln k}$$

now you can calculate the derivative (you have a composition, so you use the chain rule) and get

$$e^{k\cdot ln k}\cdot (k\cdot \frac1k + 1\cdot \ln k)=k^k\cdot (1+\ln k)$$

Comment: thanks, sometimes I'm stupid.. I will never ever make such a mistake again!!

Comment: @grp You may or may not be stupid, that's not for me to judge. But The fact that you made such a mistake does not show you are stupid, it shows you are inexperienced. Which is normal, everybody was at one point in their life inexperienced. And, I don't want to sound pessimistic, buy I can guarantee that you will make a similar mistake again, unless you stop doing math altogether. Mistakes like these are a vital part of learning. Don't be ashamed when you make them.

Comment: @5xum Well, he just said he is "sometimes stupid" which just means, sometimes people do stupid things because they lack concentration or experience.

Answer (score 3):

$$
0 < \frac{1+k}{k^k} < \frac{1+k}{k^2} \to 0
\text{ as }
k \to \infty
$$

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively what L'Hopital rule says that if the rate at which the function in the denominator(say $g(x)$) is increasing is more than the rate at which the function in the numerator(say $f(x)$) is increasing then at infinity the value of $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} \frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=0$. This is precisely what is happening in this case.